# Is it possible to use registers in Operator-pending mode? If not, why?

Tags: key-bindings

In *Normal* and *Visual* modes you can execute a motion or other operation using the contents of a register with `@`.  This `@` key does not work however in *Operator-pending* mode.  Is there another way to use a motion from a register with an operator?

In *Operator-pending* mode it is still possible to use commands as motions, for example: `:call <SID>MyAction()<CR>`.  What would be the reason for not allowing registers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The technical reason is that the `@` command isn't defined in operator pending mode. Why? Probably because it wasn't in vi, and because it only makes sense when the register actually contains a motion.

You can work around this via `:normal`, though, e.g. `qq3eqgU:normal! @q<CR>`.